# How to do operations on a class object? C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following function inside a class:

```
void solveMaze::getLoc() {
    mouse m;
    x = m.x;
    y = m.y;
    coords c(x, y);
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

This is Coords class, Is this the right way to overload the << operator?:

```
class coords {
    public:
        coords(int, int);
        int x;
        int y;
        coords& operator<<(const coords& rhs);
};


coords& coords::operator<<(const coords& rhs) {
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
}

coords::coords(int a, int b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```

I get an error "no match for operator<<"

Comment: You seem to need [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: in the code you show there is no object. You first will have to create an object of this class if you want to call its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ive figured it out:

```
class coords {
    public:
        coords();
        coords(int, int);
        int x;
        int y;
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const coords &c);
};


ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const coords &c) {
    output << c.x << " " << c.y;
    return output;
}

coords::coords(int a, int b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```